# Magento: Switch From Grid view To List View, Without Changing URL

Tags: magento

I was wondering if you could guide me how to allow the user to select either list or grid view, without changing the URL of the catalog/category page.

I.e., the page is either www.example.com/category?mode=grid OR www.example.com/category?mode=list but I want to make it just www.example.com/category and show the grid view by default, with the list view being displayed without changing the URL.

I hope you can help

Comment: You have to load all views initially and manage view by Js ...

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Are there any tutorials you could direct me to? I've been searching for hours and I just can't find a way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

There is no tutorial I guess..you have to do your own code ..And its not a big deal .. Open your `list.phtml` file in `app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/product/`

Here you can see, they separate two view mode like this,

```
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?> 
 ..bla.. bla ...
```

And Grid mode:

```
<?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>
```

Here  they check the mode like this

`<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>`

Just remove this condition, so that you can load both views, so now just add new css class or id to separate  both modes, and manage them by Js like onclik event or something like that ...

Comment: Thank you so much @Elavarasan, this is really great. As I am a novice programmer, could you direct me to a tutorial that could guide me through the steps needed to implement the javascript part of your answer?